# Campaign Influence working behaviour

Tags: apex, configuration, campaign, campaign-influence

Let's say an `Opportunity` is created and closed won yesterday with a buyer name attached. And that buyer is not attached to any campaign yesterday, but is attached to a Campaign today. Do we see that `Campaign` in the above `Opportunity` record's `Campaign Influence` Related List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is outlined in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=campaigns_influence_setup.htm&type=0):

> You can configure influential campaigns to be automatically added to opportunities. When automatic association is enabled, influential campaigns are added to opportunities when a campaign is related to a contact that is assigned a contact role on an opportunity **prior to the close date** of the opportunity. For example, if you have an email campaign with a member who is assigned a contact role on an **open opportunity**, the email campaign will be added to the Campaign Influence related list for that opportunity. *(Emphasis Added)*

Only campaigns added a number of days before the opportunity close date are considered influential.